# Axios CORS/Preflight failing with Laravel 5.4 API call

Tags: php, cors, laravel-5.4, axios, mixed-content

I'm having an issue with Laravel 5.4 and my React application which uses Axios to handle requests.

Here is the error I'm getting.
[image: Error]

Here are my request headers for the preflight response which is failing.
[image]

Here is the failed request after the preflight:
[image]

Here is my Axios request configuration:

```
let req = axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: https://api.vendorgraphs.com/{queryStringHere}
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
});
```

One interesting thing to note is that it is specifying the endpoint using the HTTPS protocol. Similar requests on my application are working as they should be but this is the only one that is failing. Is it because of the use of a query string?

The request is hitting an API endpoint as a GET request. I'm using Laravel and the laravel-cors package to handle my cors requests.

Here is my configuration for CORS:

This is in my Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

and my cors.php in the config folder

```
return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ["GET", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

I can obviously see that the preflight is failing in the network tab. What I don't understand though is why I'm getting a Mixed Content error instead of a 405 or some other HTTP status code. Seems strange that its saying I'm requesting an endpoint using the HTTP protocol when I'm explicitly setting the url using HTTPS.

I've been stuck on this for some time now and could use some insight on the issue. 
It seems like a lot of people have had "similar" issues with OPTIONS preflights. I've done things like creating a middleware that just returns a 200 HTTP status code if the method for the request is OPTIONS. But that didn't work either. Changing the request to OPTIONS for Axios and changing the route on Laravel to something like:

```
Route::options("/api/endpoint", controller@method);
```

did not work either. I just don't understand why it's redirecting to HTTP protocols and returning mixed content errors when it seems like that has nothing to do with CORS but the preflight request is failing which is indicative of it being a CORS issue. Any and all insight is appreciated.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Edited with htaccess configuration. could this be an elastic beanstalk issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem you’re seeing is, that server itself redirects the `https` URL to `http`:

```
$ curl -I 'https://api.vendorgraphs.com/api/dealershipvendorleads/?id=3,4&startDate=2017-4&endDate=2017-8'

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2017 15:33:50 GMT
Location: http://api.vendorgraphs.com/api/dealershipvendorleads?id=3,4&startDate=2017-4&endDate=2017-8
Server: Apache
Connection: keep-alive
```

Notice the `301` status code, and the `Location` header with `http://api.vendorgraphs.com/…`

So what that means is, you can’t make a cross-origin request to that API endpoint from a secure context (`https` page) without browsers blocking it as mixed content (as you’re seeing).

So this isn’t really a CORS issue — instead it’s purely a mixed-content problem.

Comment: I don't see me redirecting to HTTP anywhere. I'm using elastic beanstalk to host the laravel application. could it be an issue with that?

Comment: Right, *you* aren’t redirecting anywhere—instead the server running `api.vendorgraphs.com` is redirecting your request: It’s taking your  `https://api.vendorgraphs.com` request (secure https) and redirecting it to `http://api.vendorgraphs.com` (insecure http). That’s what the 301 status code and Location header in the answer indicate. And there’s nothing you can do from your side to fix that.

Comment: Couldn't I write a rewrite rule to force https in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I guess my question is, why does this only occur with this specific request? Is it the use of the query string? I have other requests similar to this besides the fact that the ID parameter has multiple values in this one. Does the query string and content type: 'application/json' have anything to do with this error? should i be sending them as a different content type?

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn’t occur just with that specific request and it has nothing to do with the query string. You will still get an https->http 301 if you make a request to `https://api.vendorgraphs.com/api/dealershipvendorleads/` with no query string at all, right? (Try it) If you control the `api.vendorgraphs.com`, then as far as I see what you need to do is, go in there to server environment  and find the place in the server config that’s causing that Permanent [P] 301 redirect from https to http. Because there’s something in there which is doing that.

Comment: Although this wasn't explicitly an answer, it guided me in the write direction to figure out a workaround to the issue, so i'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DanielPark  And the answer is?